# Unity: if this code executes, Unity tells me that at line 43 the specified index is out of the arrays' bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

```
if (sledgeImpact.didDestruction)
        {
            sledgeImpact.didDestruction = false;
            Collider[] firstColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(walls[0].BoxCenter, walls[0].BoxSize, Quaternion.identity, mask);
            Debug.Log(firstColliders.Length);
            if (firstColliders.Length < 350)
            {
                int o = 0;
                MeshFilter[] meshFilters = new MeshFilter[] {};
                foreach (Collider collider in firstColliders)
                {
                    //Line 43
                    meshFilters[o] = collider.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
                    o++;
                }

            }
        }
```

I'm really having a hard time understanding arrays and i really thought this code should've worked. Anyways, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you initialize an array with Zero dimension..

replace `MeshFilter[] meshFilters = new MeshFilter[] {};`

by

`MeshFilter[] meshFilters = new MeshFilter[firstColliders.Length];`

Or better, use a List in this case:

```
List<MeshFilter> meshFilters = new List<MeshFilter>();

foreach (Collider collider in firstColliders)
{
   meshFilters.Add(collider.GetComponent<MeshFilter>());
}
```

the number of items in an array have to be defined in the initialization. with a list, you could increase or decreade as you want.

Comment: This is what i feared for... I have done this exact same thing: foreach (Collider collider in firstColliders)
{
   meshFilters.Add(collider.GetComponent<MeshFilter>());
}, But i got the exact same error. I will try again and update you if you'd like. Nonetheless thank you for your answer!

Comment: Nevermind, i got it to work. Must've done something wrong in the process of creating a list then... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
MeshFilter[] meshFilters = new MeshFilter[] {};
```

you created an empty array. Arrays are not resizable, so any index would be out of range.
Create List instead:

```
List<MeshFilter> meshFilters = new List<MeshFilter>();
```

and then, inside loop:

```
meshFilters.Add(collider.GetComponent<MeshFilter>());
```